# Read tab seperated data set with errors

Tags: r, csv, import

I have a little problem with some datasets which are containing tab seperated data, but unfortunately there are some errors in the raw data, causing problems while reading into R.

A small example for better understanding, the dataset looks like this:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3

1 2 3

4 5 6

7

8 9

10 11 12
```

The 7 8 9 part should be in one row, but is wrongly seperated into two (in the raw data). Is there any chance to correct this while reading in and not by manually changing this? Because the dataset is around 4m observations large, a manual correction would take a lot of time...

Comment: What type of separation are you using in the table? Is a row like the one above have 2 separators instead of one?

Comment: You may want to use sed to replace instances of redundant separations

Comment: Do you also have empty rows?

Comment: no, there are no empty rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is more complicated than the solution by [user zx8754](https://stackoverflow.com/users/680068/zx8754) but here it goes.

```
readWrong <- function(file, skip = 1){
  txt <- readLines(file)
  header <- txt[seq_len(skip)]
  header <- scan(what = character(), textConnection(header))
  txt <- txt[-seq_len(skip)]
  data <- scan(textConnection(txt))
  data <- matrix(data, ncol = length(header), byrow = TRUE)
  data <- as.data.frame(data)
  names(data) <- header
  data
}


readWrong("data.txt")
#  Col1 Col2 Col3
#1    1    2    3
#2    4    5    6
#3    7    8    9
#4   10   11   12
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this solution, it worked quite well

Answer (score 3):

Try this example:

```
# read the file line by line:
x <- readLines("data.txt")

# Split by " " (or in your case "\t"), and convert to dataframe with 3 columns:
res <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(strsplit(x[-1], " "), recursive = TRUE),
                         ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE))

# Add column names to dataframe:
colnames(res) <- unlist(strsplit(x[1], " "))

res
#   Col1 Col2 Col3
# 1    1    2    3
# 2    4    5    6
# 3    7    8    9
# 4   10   11   12
```

Example **data.txt** file:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7
8 9
10 11 12
```

---

**Note:** Just noticed your real data is 4 million rows, maybe this is not the most efficient way.